How to change the default gateway of wireguard client?
I am trying to link a few networks together to make them accessible to each other.
wireguard network:
|----network 1----|      |----network 2-----|
| wireguard server|<-----| wireguard clientA|
|-----------------|      |                  |
         ^               |     device Z     |
         |               |------------------|
         |
     client B


Normally, the default gateway of the wireguard network is the server itself. But more than accessing network1, I would also like to gain access to network2. Can I change the default gateway to wg client A so I can access the LAN of network 2 (for example, device Z)?
Like this:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1
MTU = 1420
*DefaultGateway = 10.0.0.1*

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
PresharedKey = 
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = example.com

something like this

Instead of changing the default gateway, should you instead a route specific to network 2? E.g. ip route add <cidr_of_network_2> via <wireguard_endpoint_in_network_2>.

There's no such thing as default gateway in WG, as in, its a L3 point-to-point link. Traffics from a "client" that is set to routed into the tunnel always goes to the/a "server". The server will L3-forward the traffics (when their destionation IP is not one of the server's) according its own route and WG config (if IP forwarding is enabled and allowed). So what you need to do is make sure the "server" have configs and routes for network 2. (You may also need additional return routes along the path or source NAT for the replies from network 2 to be able to reach the WG clients.)

I see, so all the traffic will pass to the WG server first, but it is not similar to a p2p network. I am thinking wireguard server is only doing authenticating and key exchanging when doing p2p connection.
Unfortunately, routing the traffic to network2 is not what I want to do. I was thinking I could switch network access by changing the default gateway and don't need to set multiple VPN servers.
Anyway, thank you for your clarifications.
